# Access external data within ddply - R

Tags: r, scope, plyr

**Context** :

I have a big `2D matrix` (*MAT*) with model output, `rows` correspond to `time` and `columns` to `depth`. `MTime` is a `vector` with the `time coordinate` (days of the year) and `Mdepth` another with the `Depth coordinates`

Now I have a smaller data frame with specific `coordinates` where I'd like to evaluate model outputs (it correspond to observations). It looks like :

```
    name Nobs yday LowerDepth UpperDepth
1   SiO    1  267          1          0
2   SiO    2  267          3          1
3   SiO    3  267          5          3
4   SiO    4  267          7          5
5   SiO    5   27          1          0
6   SiO    6   27          3          1
7   SiO    7   27          5          3
8   SiO    8   27          7          5
9   SiO    9  104          1          0
10  SiO   10  104          3          1
11  SiO   11  104          5          3
12  SiO   12  104          7          5
13  SiO   13  174          1          0
14  SiO   14  174          3          1
15  SiO   15  174          5          3
16  SiO   16  174          7          5
```

now I'd like to use ddply to get the corresponding value from `MAT` by averaging between `LowerDepth` and `UpperDepth`, and a certain time window around `yday`
like this

```
ddply(sta,.(name,Nobs),mutate,
         modval = mean(MAT[ which( abs(MTime-yday)<4),
                            which( MDepth>UpperDepth & MDepth<LowerDepth) ] ))
```

**Question** : The problem is `MAT` doesn't seems to be known within `ddply`.
Is there a way to access external variable from within `ddply` functions?

**A possible Answer**

I've found the following solution, but there is probably some nicer way ..
the problem , as @Roland pointed out was the use of mutate.

```
ddply(sta,.(name,time),function(d.sub){
     d=cbind( d.sub,data.frame(
       modval=mean(Varmat[ which( abs(MTime-d.sub$yday)<4),
                           which( MDepth>d.sub$UpperDepth & MDepth<d.sub$LowerDepth)] ))   
     )
   }
   )
```

Comment: Don't use `mutate`. Pass a function to `ddply` that has `MAT` as a parameter.

Comment: @Roland : Thank you but.. do you have a small example of how that might be done ?

Comment: Add reproducible data to your question (i.e., the output of `dput(sta)` and `dput(MAT)`) and I might come back to this later.